# How can i select duplicates in a dict list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, append

Python newbiew: I'm using a dict list to store an ascii character along with a score and what I would like to do now is, fill up another dict list that contains all duplicate characters (independent of the score). How can I do this?
I'm appendindg the values onto the list with: `lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":a[2],"confidence":a[6]})`

Comment: You should post a sample input/desired output.

Comment: What is a "dict list"?

Comment: @RoryDaulton a list of dictionaries, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` class from collections module. One possible solution (works even if ascii_code is integer value):

```
from collections import Counter

lpdictlist = []
# lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":a[2],"confidence":a[6]})
lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":'a', "confidence":1})
lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":'b', "confidence":2})
lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":'a', "confidence":4})
lpdictlist.append({"ascii_code":'d', "confidence":10})

c = Counter(i['ascii_code'] for i in lpdictlist)
new_list = [k for k, v in c.items() if v > 1]
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
['a']
```